# EntityExistsException When Attempting Bulk Delete With OpenJPA

Tags: jpa, openjpa

I have three classes: Location, MTFCC, and BorderPoint.

Location has a unidirectional @ManyToOne relationship with MTFCC, which is intended only as a Lookup table. No cascading is defined.

Location also has a bidirectional @ManyToOne/@OneToMany with BorderPoint. Since I want all associated BorderPoint objects to delete when I delete a Location, I set cascadetype.ALL on the Location side of the relationship.

Unfortunately, an EntityExistsException is being thrown when I attempt to delete a location:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException: Cannot delete or update 
a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mapmaker`.`BORDERPOINT`, 
CONSTRAINT `BORDERPOINT_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`LOCATIONID`) REFERENCES `LOCATION`
(`LOCATIONID`)) {prepstmnt 21576566 DELETE t0, t1 FROM LOCATION t0 INNER JOIN 
MTFCC t1 ON t0.MTFCCID = t1.MTFCCID WHERE (t0.STATEFP = ? AND t1.MTFCCCODE = ?)
[params=?, ?]} [code=1451, state=23000]

[ERROR] FailedObject: DELETE t0, t1 FROM LOCATION t0 INNER JOIN MTFCC t1 ON 
t0.MTFCCID = t1.MTFCCID WHERE (t0.STATEFP = ? AND t1.MTFCCCODE = ?) 
[java.lang.String]
```

It looks like it's attempting to delete the associated MTFCC object which I do NOT want to happen. I do, however, want the associated BorderPoint objects to be deleted.

Here is the code (chopped down a bit):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Entity
@Table(name="LOCATION")
@DetachedState(enabled=true)
public class Location implements Serializable, IsSerializable, Cloneable {

private Long id;
private String stateGeoId;
private MTFCC mtfcc;
private List<BorderPoint> borderPointList;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="LOCATIONID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="MTFCCID")
public MTFCC getMtfcc() {
    return mtfcc;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "location", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public List<BorderPoint> getBorderPointList() {
    return borderPointList;
}
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BORDERPOINT")
@DetachedState(enabled = true)
public class BorderPoint implements Serializable, IsSerializable {

private Long id;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="BORDERID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Location.class)
@JoinColumn(name="LOCATIONID")
public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MTFCC")
public class MTFCC implements Serializable, IsSerializable {

    private Long id;
    private String mtfccCode;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "MTFCCID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

// etc
```

}

And, for good measure, here is the deletion code:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public int removeByStateGeoIdAndMtfcc(String stateGeoId, String mtfccCode) throws RepositoryException {

    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    String jpaQuery = "DELETE FROM Location L where L.stateFP = ?1 AND L.mtfcc.mtfccCode = ?2";
    int affectedRows = 0;
    Query query = em.createQuery(jpaQuery).setParameter(1, stateGeoId).setParameter(2, mtfccCode);

    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        affectedRows = query.executeUpdate();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //log.debug("Exception: ", e);
        throw new RepositoryException(e);
    }
    em.close();

    return affectedRows;
}
```

Hopefully I copied all relevant parts... can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't reading the error message correctly. It says that the deletion is forbidden because of the foreign key constraint between `BorderPoint` and `Location`.

The cascade delete would work if you used `em.remove(location)` to delete your `Location`. Using a delete query like you're doing won't automagically delete the `BorderPoint`s before deleting the location.

Either load them and remove them using `em.remove`, or execute other delete queries before to delete the `BorderPoint`s.

Comment: Thanks... the docs about bulk deletions didn't make that clear to me. Let me try it and make sure it works, then I'll accept your answer (might take me a day or so).

Comment: OpenJPA hit my last nerve and I'm ripping it out in favor of hibernate, but you definitely deserve the accept. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jason: Hibernate will have the exact same behaviour in this case. This is standard JPA. Now, you might have other reasons to switch.